# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline wipes out App Service Deployment Slot

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template, infrastructure-as-code

I'm building a Azure DevOps Release Pipeline that basically has 2 parts:

1. Deploy Arm Template that builds out the App Plan, App Service, Deployment slot, config settings.
   Note: I am deploying the ARM template in "incremental mode" so if the template hasn't changed this task shouldn't make any changes to the environment.
2. Deploys the Web App's code to the staging slot.

The goal obviously is to create the environment if it's not there with the ARM template  or in the case of deployments after the first "set right" the environment if there's been drift in the infrastructure.  All the things you want infrastructure as code to do.

Then the second part deploys the latest version of the application to the staging slot so it can be given a smoke test before swapping it into production.

The initial first deployment works as expected but the second, where there's no change for the ARM template to make and a new version of the application is deployed doesn't work as expected.  After running the Release Pipeline I expect to find version 1 of the application in the production slot and version 2 in the staging slot.  Instead what I find is version 2 of the app in the staging slot and an empty production slot.  This would obviously make for an outage in production so I know I must doing something wrong.

If I run the ARM Template deployment step of the Pipeline it either blows away the version 1 of the application that was in the production slot OR it swaps the slots and deploys Version 2 of the application over Version 1.

Am I doing it wrong and the ARM template need to be in it's own pipeline because it's expected behavior to wipe out the production slot?  Again, I am deploying the ARM template in "incremental mode".

**Desired behavior:** I would expect when the Pipeline runs again that the ARM Template would leave the code deployed previously in the production slot intact. Instead after the code deployment tasks runs the new code is deployed to the vNext (staging) slot and the production slot is empty with the stock "Your app service is up and running. Time to take the next step and deploy your code." message.

The Release Pipeline has 2 tasks:

1. **ARM Template Deployment V3** (Microsoft)
   Deployment mode: Incremental
2. **Azure App Service Deploy V4** (Microsoft)
   Deploy to Slot or App Service Environment: **checked**
   Resource Group and Slot Name provided

ARM Template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "webAppName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "skuTier": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "skuName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "appInsightsName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ceEndPoint": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ceStoreRoute": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ceMask1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ceMask2": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ceClientValidateURL": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ceClientId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ceClientNo": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "stagingSlotName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "SCSU Department": "ITS",
        "SCSU SME": "MAA"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourcegroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "httpsOnly": true
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webAppName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(concat('microsoft.insights/components/', parameters('appInsightsName'))).InstrumentationKey]",
            "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~2",
            "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode": "recommended",
            "DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION": "disabled",
            "APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION": "disabled",
            "APPINSIGHTS_SNAPSHOTFEATURE_VERSION": "disabled",
            "InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION": "disabled",
            "SnapshotDebugger_EXTENSION_VERSION": "disabled",
            "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions": "disabled",
            "ceEndPoint": "[parameters('ceEndPoint')]",
            "ceStoreRoute": "[parameters('ceStoreRoute')]",
            "ceMask1": "[parameters('ceMask1')]",
            "ceMask2": "[parameters('ceMask2')]",
            "ceClientValidateURL": "[parameters('ceClientValidateURL')]",
            "ceClientId": "[parameters('ceClientId')]",
            "ceClientNo": "[parameters('ceClientNo')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "web",
      "tags": {
        "SCSU Department": "ITS",
        "SCSU SME": "MAA"
      },
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
        "reserved": false
      },
      "sku": {
        "tier": "[parameters('skuTier')]",
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '/', parameters('stagingSlotName'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "SCSU Department": "ITS",
        "SCSU SME": "MAA"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webAppName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
      },
      "resources": []
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
      "name": "[parameters('appInsightsName')]",
      "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "string",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webAppName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "SCSU Department": "ITS",
        "SCSU SME": "MAA"
      },
      "properties": {
        "Application_Type": "web",
        "ApplicationId": "[parameters('webAppName')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What does your ARM template look like? What does your pipeline look like?

Comment: Added ARM template and pipeline tasks, I'm not sure what the best way would be to post all the options in the pipeline tasks but I'm not doing much beyond the default settings and filling in required fields.  For the ARM Deploy task I'm using the "Override template parameters" for passing in variables instead of using a parameters file.

Comment: This question should be reopened, all additional debugging information that was asked for was provided and desired behavior was also called out.

Answer (score 1):

If your web app is running from package, which I believe is the default in Azure DevOps App Service deploy task, you need to add the following appsetting in the ARM template:

```
"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE": "1"
```

Comment: I had the same problem and adding this setting in the ARM template fixed it. Thanks.